# Select between percent signs in sublime

Tags: sublimetext3

I want to know if can modify something so that when I double click I select the word between `%` characters. For example: 
%**select_this**%.

The mousemap in sublime shows this:

```
{
    "button": "button1", "count": 2,
    "press_command": "drag_select",
    "press_args": {"by": "words"}
}
```

I want to know if `{"by": "words"}` is like a regex in another file. So if I find that file I can modify to now select inside `%` like it currently does for `"` and `'`.

Or, maybe I can modify `"press_args": {"by": "words"}` for a regex there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what constitutes a "word" is defined in your user (or syntax specific) preferences. To be precise, ST uses the `word_separators` setting to infer where a word begins and ends.

You can add `%` to your `word_separators` to enable double left clicking inside `%select_this%` to not select the percentage symbols.

As can be seen when opening the default and user settings from the Preferences -> Settings menu, the default value includes `%`:

```
"word_separators": "./\\()\"'-:,.;<>~!@#$%^&*|+=[]{}`~?",
```

so probably you will need to edit the value assigned in the right hand pane of Preferences -> Syntax Specific.